# Can anyone solve the error in Spark databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

My SQL request:

```sql
SELECT Incident Number FROM fireIncidents where Incident Date='04/04/2016'
```

Error in SQL statement:

> ParseException:
> mismatched input 'Date' expecting {, ';'}(line 1, pos 57)

Comment: I'm not databricks expert, but should the date format be: `2021-04-04`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in `Incident Date` column.

If you want spark to know the column has space, use ` symbol in start and end of col.

Same as `Incident Number` col.

```
SELECT `Incident Number` FROM fireIncidents where `Incident Date`='04/04/2016'
```

If your `Incident Date` col is a date, you can cast it to spark format, use

```
select `Incident Date`, to_date(`Incident Date`, 'dd/MM/yyyy') FROM fireIncidents""").show()
```

which yields

```
+-------------+----------------------------------+
|Incident Date|to_date(Incident Date, dd/MM/yyyy)|
+-------------+----------------------------------+
|   04/04/2016|                        2016-04-04|
|   04/04/2016|                        2016-04-04|
|   04/04/2016|                        2016-04-04|
+-------------+----------------------------------+
```